# Additional Attributes

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I saw you helped someone out. I am just seeing if you could assist me as well. I am using Magento 2 now instead of Magento 1. I have created my attributes for each of my products but in Magento 1 it would separate these fields in excel and I was able to upload them rapidly. Magento 2 now it seems like it adds them all to one cell and it's under additional attributes, is there a way I could separate these cell for import and export?
Thank you so much. 
Saied.

Answer (score 0):

Putting custom product attributes into a single column for product import is a very easy process.

Simply put all your custom attribute in following way into the column with name additional_attributes into your imported CSV file.

```
Custom_attribute_1="value_1",Custom_attribute_2="value_2",Custom_attribute_3="value_3",Custom_attribute_4="value_4"
```

Although it is better to follow Magento's standard way of importing custom product attributes, there is a [paid extension](https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-import-export-product-attributes.html) which you can try if you want the custom attributes as separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free extension that can help you with the exporting process: [BSS Custom Product Attribute Export](https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-custom-product-attribute-export-extension.html).

It states that you can select which attributes to "break out" into their own separate columns in the exported CSV file.

For imports, I believe you can have custom attributes in their own columns and they will still be imported.